# How to remove close icon on inappupdate screen

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-update

I am using **in_app_update** package and would like to force the user to update the app before proceeding. This package works fine however when it prompts the user for update, there is a close icon at the top right corner, which implies that the user can close the prompt and proceed with using the app. Is there a way to remove the icon so that the user has no other option but to update the app?

Here's the screenshot of the screen.
[image]

Comment: hii what are the steps you have done for this to work

Comment: I haven't been able to make this work honestly. I posted this question on their github page as well.

Comment: me got always no update available status code 1 , did you got that problem well?

Comment: You need to try it with the app downloaded from playstore.

Comment: Did you achieved this